# No se muestran los datos en el listview con SQLite (Android studio)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Estoy creando una aplicación en android studio, sobre un menú de una cafetería, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando la persona le de clic al boton de "hamburguesa bbq" (por dar un ejemplo) se despliegue un cuadro de diálogo que pregunte si realmente quiere agregar a la orden la hamburguesa, se supone que cuando le dan clic en "SI" se abre una nueva activity llamada "Pedidos" y en esta activity se muestra en una listview lo que vas ordenando (nombre de la comida y el costo de la comida), mi problema es que lo estoy haciendo con SQLite (me base en varios tutoriales de youtube) y al momento de que se abre la activity de "Pedidos" no se muestra nada en la lista y el código no me marca ningún error.

Antes de que le pusiera el SQLite si se mostraba, pero se borraba cada vez que cambiaba de pantalla o cuando agregaba otra cosa a la orden.

**MyDBHandler.java**

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "comida.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "comidas";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_COSTO = "costocomida";
public static final String COLUMN_NOMBRECOMIDA = "comida";

public MyDBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
    COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_NOMBRECOMIDA + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_COSTO + " TEXT" +
            ")");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);
}
public void close(){
    this.close();
}

public void addComida(String comida, String costocomida) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NOMBRECOMIDA, comida);
    values.put(COLUMN_COSTO, costocomida);
    this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
}

public Cursor getComida() {
    String[] columnas = {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NOMBRECOMIDA, COLUMN_COSTO};
    Cursor c = this.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_PRODUCTS, columnas, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}
}
```

**Hamburguesas.java**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Hamburguesas extends AppCompatActivity {
Button bbq;
int costohamburguesa = 0;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hamburguesas);
    bbq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bbq);

    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this);

        bbq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Hamburguesas.this);
            mBuilder.setTitle("AGREGAR");
            mBuilder.setMessage("¿Desea agregar a su orden?");
            mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    costohamburguesa = 40;
                    String costohamburguesabbq = Integer.toString(costohamburguesa);
                    String nombre = bbq.getText().toString();
                    dbHandler.addComida(nombre,costohamburguesabbq);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Hamburguesas.this,Pedidos.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                }
            });
            mBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = mBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();            }
    });
```

**Pedidos.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Pedidos extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView list;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
Button regresarmenu;
int costocomida;
String comida;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;
Button mostrar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedidos);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mostrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mostrar);

    showNotes();

        //botón para regresar al menú
        regresarmenu = findViewById(R.id.regresarmenu);
        regresarmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Pedidos.this, Menu.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
private void showNotes() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this);
        Cursor c = dbHandler.getComida();
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String title;
        String content;
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                title = c.getString(1);
                content = c.getString(2);
                arrayList.add(title + "         $" + content);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapters = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, arrayList);
        list.setAdapter(adapters);
        adapters.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
}
```